# Differential Equation result

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So im doing a differential equation and I turned it into the integration form but now im having trouble at solving  it, and cant find anything yet. The integral:

$$\int \frac{ds}{\ln(s)+5}$$

Comment: There's no elementary solution to this integral. What is the original question?

Comment: Determine wheter the given differential equation is separable and the equation is$ds/dt = tln(s^2t)+8t^2$ but i want to solve the integral that this equation give me.